# How to inject an object with parameters into a function in other object

Tags: swift, swiftui, dependency-injection

How can I inject `TaskDetails` inside the `doSomething(taskDetails:)` function located inside the `TaskService` class?

In the following testing example I'm using Ints to represent dates, please note that this is just for show-and-tell purposes.

##### Task Object

```
class Task:NSObject{
    var name = ""
    var dueDate:Int = 0
    
    init(name: String, dueDate: Int) {
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

##### Task TaskDetails

```
class TaskDetails{
    var task: Task
    
    init(task: Task){
        self.task = task
    }
    
    var hasExpired:Bool{
        /// in production I have some calculations based on creationDate, dueDate and todays date
        let todaysDate = 10
        if todaysDate < task.dueDate{
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

##### Task TaskService

```
class TaskService{
    // what would be the best way to inject TaskDetails
    func doSomething(taskDetails: TaskDetails){
        // I need to access property taskDetails.hasExpired
    }
}
```

FYI - I could restructure my `TaskDetails` object and remove `Task` from the initializer but I made it this way since I couldn't find another way to use `TaskDetails` inside `SwiftUI`.

### REF CODE

##### SwiftUI Code

Just as a reference and to demonstrate how I'm using it and why I had to add `Task` inside the initializer.

```
struct TestingGeneral: View {
    let todos = [Task(name: "Do Laundry", dueDate:5), Task( name:"Get Milk", dueDate:20)]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(todos, id: \.self) { item in
                let details = TaskDetails(task: item)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("\(item.name) - ")
                    
                    // here I'm using the TaskDetails object
                    if details.hasExpired{
                        Text("Expired!")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }else{
                        Text("Good!")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I could find to make `TaskDetails` work in SwiftUI was by adding `let details = TaskDetails(task: item)` inside the `ForEach`.

Comment: You may want to consider using a different name besides `Task`, which is already used in Swift concurrency.

Comment: The presented code is just testing classes not related to the project I'm working on but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add a computed property to your view where you map from Task (bad name btw) to TaskDetails or perform the mapping earlier depending on what your real source of truth is for Task

```
var details: [TaskDetails] {
    todos.map(TaskDetails.init)
}

var body: some View {
    List{
        ForEach(details) { item in
            //...
```

For the above ForEach to work you need to make TaskDetails conform to Identifiable

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that I no longer have access to `Task` name.  Please note that I'm using other attributes from `Task`  directly in SwiftUI. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, you can do `item.task.name`? Or create a wrapper method on TaskDetails

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. I'll restructure my class to remove the dependency from the initializer. Thanks a lot.